# ReactJS: Cannot read property 'value' of null when getting selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do is get the value of the selected `<option>` from the `<select>` elemenet however in my current code, I keep getting an error saying:

> cannot read property 'value' of null.

This is very frustrating considering I've tried the methods I found online and yet it still doesn't work properly. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyClass extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedItem: ""
        };
    }

    onChange() {
        var selectedItem = document.getElementById("selectItem").value
        this.setState({selectedItem: selectedItem})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <select id="selectItem" defaultValue="option1" onChange={this.onChange()}>
                    <option value="option1">option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">option2</option>
                    <option value="option3">option3</option>
                    <option value="option4">option4</option>
                </select>

                <div>{this.state.selectedItem}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyClass
```

I would like it to display what option is being selected within the div.  If possible I would also like it to show the defaultValue upon loading the page as well.

Comment: You're calling the function (`onChange={this.onChange()}`). You should use `onChange={this.onChange}`, in any case, using `document.getElementById` in a ReactJS app is not the way to go.

Comment: @Titus if you could show your solution to not using getElementById that would be awesome.  I would like to eliminate it if I can, just the only way I know how to get that value atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the context of `onChange` is not that of your MyClass component instance, meaning that when `onChange` is called, `this` won't be the corresponding instance of `MyClass`.

The problem can be resolved by adding this line to your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedItem: ""
    };

    // Add this
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

#### Update

One way to load the default value of the `<select>` dynamically:

```
class MyClass extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedItem: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        /* Set initally selected value to say, option3 */
        this.setState({ selectedItem : "option3" })
    }

    onChange() {
        var selectedItem = document.getElementById("selectItem").value
        this.setState({selectedItem: selectedItem})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                {/* 
                Specify the select value which will show as option3 by
                default 
                */}
                <select id="selectItem" value={ this.selectedItem }
                        onChange={this.onChange()}>
                    <option value="option1">option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">option2</option>
                    <option value="option3">option3</option>
                    <option value="option4">option4</option>
                </select>

                <div>{this.state.selectedItem}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked!  Is there any way that I can load the defaultValue upon loading my page via componentDidMount()? Or will that not work?

Comment: @Michael you're welcome - just updated answer, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `this.onChange` while the element is created, while the `onChange` attribute is set (`onChange={this.onChange()}`).

You should use just `onChange={this.onChange}` (without the parenthesis `()`).

Beside that, `document.getElementById` is not how you access the DOM in a ReactJS app, actually, you don't need to access the DOM in this case.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class MyClass extends Component{
    state = {
        selectedItem: ""
    };

    onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
        this.setState({ selectedItem: value })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <select id="selectItem" defaultValue="option1" onChange={this.onChange}>
                    <option value="option1">option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">option2</option>
                    <option value="option3">option3</option>
                    <option value="option4">option4</option>
                </select>

                <div>{this.state.selectedItem}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyClass
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer!